# Checking where a series of functions is uniformly convergent, an application of Weierstrass M-Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$fn(x) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x^2)^n}{(1+x^2)^n}sin(nx)$
I am attempting to figure out where this series is uniformly and absolutely convergent.
I am trying to use M-Test,
if 0 < x < 1  then   $0<x^2<1$ 
so |$\frac{(1-x^2)^n}{(1+x^2)^n}sin(nx)|<\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} $
the RHS is convergent geometric series, so I applied M-test.
Is this the correct approach to use?
And how do I check that this series is not uniformly convergent on x>1.

Comment: To prove uniform convergence, you need a majorant which is independent of $x$.

Comment: It is also convergent for $x=\pm 1$ and $x =n\pi$.

Comment: @Gary by Majorant do you mean the upper bound?

Comment: Yes, to show uniform convergence on an interval $I$, you may give a sequence $a_n$ (independent of $x$) such that $
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {f_n (x)} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {a_n }  <  + \infty$ for all $x$ in $I$.

Comment: @Gary so I cant prove uniform convergence on (0,1) but if I use [a,1) for some a>0, then i can make the upper bound independent of x then use M test?

Comment: Yes, your guess that the convergence is not uniform on $(0,1)$ is correct, but you have to prove it. Show that the terms do not tend uniformly to $0$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: if I use xn = 1/n, then fn(xn) doesn't uniformly converge to zero, does that show that the series is also not uniformly convergent ?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer. The series is not uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, -1)$: If it is uniformly convergent there then the general term must tend to $0$ uniformly. But then $\sin (nx) \to 0$ uniformly. Take $x=\frac {2m\pi} n+\frac {\pi} {2n}$ with $m$ large to get a contradiction.

By M-test the series converges uniformly on $\{x: \epsilon \leq |x| \leq 1\}$ for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

Comment: by general term do you mean fn(x), or the partial sums?

Comment: The $n-$th term of the series $f_n(x)$. @saluzulfi

Comment: if I use xn = 1/n, then fn(xn) doesn't uniformly converge to zero, does that show that the series is also not uniformly convergent on (0,1)?

Comment: @saluzulfi Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so the series doesn't converge uniformly on [a,1), a>0 either? How is that so?

Comment: @saluzulfi Answer corrected.